# Margin Widget Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I've always wondered why Flutter doesn't have a Margin Widget but do have a Padding Widget?
Note: I know that I can access both properties using a Container Widget.

Answer (score 0):

:v Aren't they are the same? "A margin is the space around an element's border, while padding is the space between an element's border and the element's content". If you Padding widget or Margin widget (if Flutter have), they also create a space from child to Padding/Margin widget - obviously same purpose. When you use Container, you can create a border and now you would see the difference.